# Server created using hazelcast-3.6.jar is not picking up configs from hazelcast.xml

Tags: hazelcast

I am using spring boot to test my Rest API's with hazelcast-3.6 as the DB.I am using hazelcast-3.6.jar to setup a server.The server created this way is not picking up properties from hazelcast.xml provided.Can someone guide me how to make it pick up the properties from hazelcast.xml?

Comment: please, attach your Spring config here.

Comment: dear user2966021, did you have a chance to review the answers? Please, select right answer or provide more details of your issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run you program with `-Dhazelcast.config=<path to hazelcast.xml>` or put your hazelcast.xml in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put the hazelcast.xml to the right directory.
Please check the `Checking configuration` manual section where it's explained what's the order of config file check:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#checking-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Please find the examples of using Hazelcast with Spring Boot [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/springboot-caching).
[Here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/spring-configuration) you can find how to configure Hazelcast with Spring.